# avoiding gmail's spam filter?

Tags: email, gmail

I am trying to allow users on my site to send invitations to their friends. The script works fine, except that gmail thinks it's spam. I'm using my own website's email address and name as the from email and using the correct first and last name of the recipient.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening? It does the same thing to important notifications I send out (like if their account has been reported and in danger of being banned, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Route all emails through a real SMTP service. Sending email from a webserver with the headers altered will (correctly) be identified as looking like spam.